# Why was the Bay of Pigs invasion unsuccessful?

Tags: war, cold-war

Goal of The Bay of Pigs invasion in April,1961. was to overthrow Cuba's president Castro. It was totally unsuccesful and counter-revolutionary military, trained by CIA was defeated in just two days. As wikipedia says, Dwight Eisenhower allocated $13.1 million to the CIA in order to plan Castro's overthrow. Also, they were supplied good and had good armament.My question is what is the reason why was the Bay of Pigs invasion unsuccessful? I  mean all the reasons above lead that USA could overthrow Castro. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_of_Pigs_Invasion#Later_analysis

Comment: The invaders were not experienced, trained soldiers, just a ragtag bunch of refugees. Castro had an army that had been fighting in the mountains for 3 years and had 2 more years to arm itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unless the question indicates how wikipedia fails to answer the question, then it is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Plausible deniability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability) limited the resources allocated.
2. Intelligence failure greatly overestimated the internal tensions of the Castro regime.